# Can I use a timer to keep a refrigerator from freezing its contents?

Tags: electrical

I have a small refrigerator that I want to utilize with a timer. We use this mini fridge for drinks and it freezes drinks on top shelf. I thought of turning it off overnight.

Would a UL-rated timer rated for 15 amps, 1/2 or 3/4 HP, and 125 volts be adequate? I am also wondering if startup watts exceeds this timer.

[image: label from fridge below.]

Comment: Question is why.  Fridges/freezers already have a timer built in, so they only work when needed, get warm, cool off.  For trying to save power use, a timer might cause higher power use since the fridge will need more time to cool down.  Not even adding food going bad.

Comment: We use this mini fridge for drinks and it freezes drinks on top shelf. Thought of turning off overnight

Comment: It seems like the temperature needs adjustment.  Should be a dial with warmer/colder or numbers.

Comment: In looking at pictures of this model, are the beverages that are freezing directly under the freezer compartment?  This fridge model does not look to have any air circulation built in, so relies on non-forced air convection to keep things cold throughout the fridge.  I'd suggest (especially if you keep this fridge quite full) to reduce the contents of the fridge to allow better air circulation throughout the space and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently a bit of an XY question, so I'm going to answer both the question you asked, and the question you implied with your follow-up comments. First, the question you asked:

> Will a 15 amp UL rated timer work for this fridge?

Almost certainly yes. If it fails, the failure mode is likely to be 'fail open' or 'weld closed', and since it's UL listed that won't be dangerous. It's far more likely that it will Just Work.

Now the question you implied:

> How do I get this fridge to be less cold?

There are external thermostats available for fridges. They are often used for turning chest freezers in to refrigerators. I have one in my basement right now with a chest freezer hooked up to it to make a very efficient drinks fridge. They are relatively inexpensive and can add digital temperature control to your fridge with the simple addition of a temperature sensor and a box that plugs inline with your fridge. The keywords 'external refrigerator thermostat' in your favorite search engine will get you started. You can add precise temperature control to your fridge with one in minutes.

Answer (score 0):

After writing this, I read a comment about a problem with drinks freezing. That basically means poor temperature setting. A timer isn't the solution, adjusting the thermostat is the solution. And if the thermostat has gone bad, replacing the thermostat.

A starting point is a good digital thermometer. I use [some of these Accurite from Amazon](https://amzn.to/43wVNcv):

[image: Accurite thermomemters]

but there are plenty of others available, including some that automatically record history so you can analyze the results. Which reminds me of this **must watch video** from [Technology Connections](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8PTjPzw9VhY) which discusses many of the possible issues - and some fixes - with refrigerator design.

I have also found over the years that "dorm refrigerators" like OP's have relatively bad temperature control compared to full-size refrigerators. This particular model, which seems quite typical, has a top shelf that is right next to the freezer compartment. Unlike a full-size refrigerator, the freezer compartment has no significant insulation from the main refrigerated compartment, so it is not surprising that items on that top shelf freeze.

##### Frame Challenge

Do **NOT** do this without a really, really good reason.

There are two reasons I can think of why you *might* want to time a refrigerator:

- Save Energy

You won't save much. This refrigerator is rated to use 0.57 kWh per day. That's on the order of 10 cents per day based on typical US electricity rates. So, assuming you don't open up the refrigerator excessively or put things in frequently that are significantly above room temperature, the total cost will be ~ $3/month. If you time it for on/off on a 50% duty cycle you won't even save $2/month, because *most of the time the refrigerator is sitting there using just a few Watts for control circuits, and possibly not even that much if it has a simple thermostat control*. Plus, any savings from not running the refrigerator for a long time (e.g., 12 hours) will be mostly lost as the compressor runs extra to catch up for previous missed compressor cycle time. FYI, by rough calculation (0.8A x 115V = 92W x 24 hr = 2,208 Wh; divide 570 Wh/2,208 Wh = 25.8%) this refrigerator is designed to run on a 25% duty cycle - e.g., 30 minutes on, 90 minutes off, but the actual cycle time will depend on refrigerator contents, ambient air temperature and open/close time.

Realistically, you'd be lucky to save even $1 per month.

- Not Cool As Much

A typical refrigerator should hold a temperature between 32 F and 40 F. A wine cooler should be somewhere between 50 F and 59 F. You might think you could turn a refrigerator into a low-budget wine cooler by running it only part of the time. But what you'd actually end up with is large swings. After 4 hours off, you might reach 55 F but then in the next two hours on go down to 34 F. And back and forth. Possibly reaching an *average* temperature significantly above 40 F, but not reliably or consistently and with a 20 degree - or even more - temperature swing. Which isn't good for most things.

Comment: OP's reason is that it gets too cold(freezing drinks) on top.  An edit might help with new information.

Comment: Yes the thermostat is set at lowest point just prior to point of shut off. Drinks freeze on top shelf

Answer (score 0):

As it's for drinks, there shouldn't be a food safety implication if the other bits don't get cold enough. So I'd do this as a quick workaround (I have a suitable timer) if the thermostat didn't adjust enough to do the job.

However I'd try a couple of other things first:

- A small amount of insulation between the closest drinks and the freezer compartment (a couple of layers of bubble wrap, for example). That's enough to avoid similar issues in my van fridge.
- making ice in the freezer compartment before putting the drinks in to chill. If you don't want ice, freezing a couple of plastic bottles 2/3 full of water. Some fridges aren't keen on running with an empty ice box, others get too cold if you make excessive demands on the freezer (like making lots of ice at once.
- rotating the contents. If this is mainly an issue when cooling drinks from room temperature, as I suspect it is, you can swap the coldest ones with the warmest, before the former freeze
- similarly, load it except the bit that's prone to freezing, wait until everything chills, then load the last bit, shifting these drinks to safer areas once there's space.

If you do use a timer, the mechanical type are probably better here. Rather than long off periods followed by on periods long enough to freeze the contents, it's probably more worth adjusting the duty cycle to be off for something like 1/4 of every hour. That's easy on mechanical timers where you click segments up and down for on and off.